# How to combine creds.json file into python script and create a gui?

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, python-requests, credentials

It's been a long road, but I had 4 separate python scripts I wanted to combine as one.

This is working and is listed below:

```
import gspread
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Set up credentials and authorize the client
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "g-league-tracker-final",
    "private_key_id": "1b8efa2e9cc9ff846ee358811687b98f0425d4ea",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "g",
    "client_id": "1",
    "auth_uri": "https://acc",
    "token_uri": "http",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/gleaguetracker%40g-league-tracker-final.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

print('STARTING G LEAGUE PROFILES')
# G Leauge PROFILES

gc = gspread.service_account(creds)
sh = gc.open_by_key('1DpasSS8yC1UX6WqAbkQ515BwEEjdDL-x74T0eTW8hLM')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('GLeague Profile Details')
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "pos_option1": pos}
        row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
  
]


res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

print('FINISHED G LEAGUE PROFILES')
print('STARTING INTERNATIONAL PROFILES')
# STARTING INTERNATIONAL PROFILES

worksheet2 = sh.worksheet('International Profile Details')
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links2(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.select('td.nowrap'):
        a_tag = td.a
        if a_tag:
            name = a_tag.text
            player_url = a_tag['href']
            pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
            print(f"Getting {name}")

            req_player_url = requests.get(
                f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
            soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
            div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "pos_option1": pos}
            row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text if div_profile_box.h2.span else None

            for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
                try:
                    key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                    row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                except:     # not all entries have values
                    pass

            data.append(row)

    return data


urls2 = ["https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc",
         "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/2"]


res2 = []
for url in urls2:
    data = get_links2(url)
    res2 = [*res2, *data]

# print(res2)

if res2 != []:
    header = list(res2[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res2]]
    worksheet2.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

print('FINISHED INTERNATIONAL PROFILES')
print('STARTING G LEAGUE PROFILES')
# STARTING GLEAGUE STATS
worksheet_name1 = "All G League Stats"
worksheet1 = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name1)

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/player/All/desc/1/Regular_Season'
res = []

for count in range(1, 99):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

data = pd.concat(res)

# Convert the data to a list of lists
values = data.values.tolist()

# Add header row
header = data.columns.tolist()
values.insert(0, header)

# Write the data to the worksheet
worksheet1.clear()  # Clear any existing data
worksheet1.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",
                       insert_data_option="INSERT_ROWS", table_range="B1")
print('FINISHED G LEAGUE STATS')
print('STARTING INTERNATIONAL STATS')
# STARTING INTERNATIONAL STATS

worksheet_name2 = "All International Stats"
worksheet2 = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name2)

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc'
res = []

for count in range(1, 95):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

data = pd.concat(res)

# Replace NaN values with an empty string
data = data.fillna("")

# Convert the data to a list of lists
values = data.values.tolist()

# Add header row
header = data.columns.tolist()
values.insert(0, header)

# Write the data to the worksheet
worksheet2.clear()  # Clear any existing data
worksheet2.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",
                       insert_data_option="OVERWRITE", table_range="B1")
```

I wanted to just wrap it in a simple GUI so that I could run from my desktop:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def update_data():
    # Set the status to "In progress"
    status_label.config(text="In progress...")
    root.update()

    # Paste your code here

    # Set the status to "Completed"
    status_label.config(text="Completed")
    root.update()
    print("Data updated.")

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.title("G League & International Finder")

# Create the title label
title_label = tk.Label(root, text="G League & International Finder", font=("Helvetica", 16))
title_label.pack(pady=10)

# Create the update data button
update_data_button = tk.Button(root, text="Update Data", font=("Helvetica", 14), command=update_data)
update_data_button.pack(pady=20)

# Create the status label
status_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12))
status_label.pack(pady=10)

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

I'm adding in the code where it's supposed to go, but receiving various errors, I thought the code should look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import gspread
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# Set up credentials and authorize the client
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "g",
    "private_key_id": "1b8efa2e9c",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\+DEpmj73dM8TUFEGuI7BSbW\ndCvEgLYRbFNE4d1AoGdxjpntne64DyzHwOKWVV0/aQKBgFZOTfyKxp16bThXmcDI\ntuZbLGK5PEP+OAsqM9lQ0DveaDXsl942LNHLKYj11+ZZ375DFmZeIHsFjcO73XuQ\nFRK9+zSsWL9PZWr18PwUUdqaLkMqh7EKoMHo2JcG9EOo6o4srdrtH8SFQoJ1Eklm\n7vzwtoJU0aGPoOqoJIxKH/z7\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "",
    "client_id": "",
    "auth_uri": "",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/gleaguetracker%40g-league-tracker-final.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

print('STARTING G LEAGUE PROFILES')
# G Leauge PROFILES

gc = gspread.service_account(creds)
sh = gc.open_by_key('1DpasSS8yC1UX6WqAbkQ515BwEEjdDL-x74T0eTW8hLM')


def update_data():
    # Set the status to "In progress"
    status_label.config(text="In progress...")
    root.update()

    # Paste your code here
worksheet = sh.worksheet('GLeague Profile Details')
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "pos_option1": pos}
        row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
  
]


res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

print('FINISHED G LEAGUE PROFILES')
print('STARTING INTERNATIONAL PROFILES')
# STARTING INTERNATIONAL PROFILES

worksheet2 = sh.worksheet('International Profile Details')
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links2(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.select('td.nowrap'):
        a_tag = td.a
        if a_tag:
            name = a_tag.text
            player_url = a_tag['href']
            pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
            print(f"Getting {name}")

            req_player_url = requests.get(
                f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
            soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
            div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "pos_option1": pos}
            row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text if div_profile_box.h2.span else None

            for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
                try:
                    key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                    row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                except:     # not all entries have values
                    pass

            data.append(row)

    return data


urls2 = ["https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc",
         "https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/minutes/All/desc/2"]


res2 = []
for url in urls2:
    data = get_links2(url)
    res2 = [*res2, *data]

# print(res2)

if res2 != []:
    header = list(res2[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res2]]
    worksheet2.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

print('FINISHED INTERNATIONAL PROFILES')
print('STARTING G LEAGUE PROFILES')
# STARTING GLEAGUE STATS
worksheet_name1 = "All G League Stats"
worksheet1 = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name1)

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/player/All/desc/1/Regular_Season'
res = []

for count in range(1, 99):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

data = pd.concat(res)

# Convert the data to a list of lists
values = data.values.tolist()

# Add header row
header = data.columns.tolist()
values.insert(0, header)

# Write the data to the worksheet
worksheet1.clear()  # Clear any existing data
worksheet1.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",
                       insert_data_option="INSERT_ROWS", table_range="B1")
print('FINISHED G LEAGUE STATS')
print('STARTING INTERNATIONAL STATS')
# STARTING INTERNATIONAL STATS

worksheet_name2 = "All International Stats"
worksheet2 = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name2)

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/stats/2023/Averages/Qualified/All/player/All/desc'
res = []

for count in range(1, 95):
    # pd.read_html accepts a URL too so no need to make a separate request
    df_list = pd.read_html(f"{url}/{count}")
    res.append(df_list[-1])

data = pd.concat(res)

# Replace NaN values with an empty string
data = data.fillna("")

# Convert the data to a list of lists
values = data.values.tolist()

# Add header row
header = data.columns.tolist()
values.insert(0, header)

# Write the data to the worksheet
worksheet2.clear()  # Clear any existing data
worksheet2.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED",
                       insert_data_option="OVERWRITE", table_range="B1")

# Set the status to "Completed"
status_label.config(text="Completed")
root.update()
print("Data updated.")


# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.title("G League & International Finder")

# Create the title label
title_label = tk.Label(
    root, text="G League & International Finder", font=("Helvetica", 16))
title_label.pack(pady=10)

# Create the update data button
update_data_button = tk.Button(root, text="Update Data", font=(
    "Helvetica", 14), command=update_data)
update_data_button.pack(pady=20)

# Create the status label
status_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12))
status_label.pack(pady=10)

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

But I'm receiving this error, is this from the credentials? I originally had it as a separate file, but needed to add it into my code so it was all together.  Not sure what is going wrong here, but any advice on how I can package this all as a gui would be much appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AMadle\GLeagueFinal\gui.py", line 32, in <module>
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 40, in authorize
    client = client_class(auth=credentials)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.auth = convert_credentials(auth)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 67, in convert_credentials
    module = credentials.__module__
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__module__'. Did you mean: '__reduce__'?
PS C:\Users\AMadle\GLeagueFinal>
```

4PM EST 3/4 UPDATE:

I was wrong - it seems like the error is definitely coming from placing CREDS directly into my file.  Like I mentioned, it was a separate file before, going to try to figure this out but if anyone has a solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I spent all day trying to combine these codes, I learned that it's not needed.  I now am creating this gui based on my folder instead - this is not a direct solution on "how to add in creds.json to python script", but it kind of gets the job done:

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk

# Set the path to the folder containing your scripts
folder_path = r"C:\Users\AMadle\GLeagueFinal"

# Define a function to run each script


def run_script(script_name):
    script_path = os.path.join(folder_path, script_name)
    creds_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "creds.json")
    subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path, creds_path])


# Create the GUI window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Script Runner")

# Define a function to run all scripts


def run_all():
    for script_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if script_name.endswith(".py"):
            run_script(script_name)


# Create buttons for each script
for script_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if script_name.endswith(".py"):
        script_button = tk.Button(
            root, text=script_name, command=lambda script_name=script_name: run_script(script_name))
        script_button.pack()

# Create a button to run all scripts
all_button = tk.Button(root, text="Run All", command=run_all)
all_button.pack()

# Start the GUI
root.mainloop()
```